# upgraded moodle 2.7.1 to php 7.0 and mysql 5.6. But unable to connect to mysql 8.0 if upgrading mysql

Tags: moodle, php-5.6, mysql-8.0, php-7.4

Moodle app is runnung with php 7 and mysql 5.6.

Whenm updating mysql version from 5.6 to 8.0.

Moodle does not connects to database for mysql 8.0[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Which version of PHP is it?

If you are using 7.1 then you'll need at least 7.1.16 or at least 7.2.4 for 7.2.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.requirements.php

### Is the new MySql 8 server using the same port?

Check the port by running this in MySql

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
```

The default in Moodle is 3306. If its different then you can change this in the config.php

```
$CFG->dboptions = array(
    'dbport' => 'yournewport'
);
```

### Upgrade Moodle 2.7

Finally, Moodle 2.7 is no longer supported. The last update was May 2017.

The recommended upgrade route is first upgrade to 2.7.20 then to 3.2.9 then to 3.8.x

https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Upgrading